# How to output the first, the middle, and the last letter of a word from a random string

Tags: javascript

E.g. grape should output gae.
If the beginning of the code looks like this,

```
var words = [ "banana", "apple", "pineapple", "orange", "pear", "grape",
  "watermelon",     "paragraph", "Avocado", "cherry", "blackberry", "coconut",
  "lime", "lemon", "olive", "plum",  "Nectarine", "mango", "apricot"];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){ 
  var n1 = Math.floor(rc4Rand.getRandomNumber() * words.length); 
  var word = words[n1]; 
  document.writeln("The word is: " + word); 
  document.writeln("1st, middle and last letters are:"); 
  output(word); 
}
```

Should I write sth like array `n1[0]`, array `[n1.length-1]`, `array[length/2]` or what to get the result? Tks for all of your comments and advices!

Comment: Whats the middle character of a word with an even number of characters?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this

```
var shortened = word.charAt(0) + // first
                word.charAt(Math.floor(word.length / 2)) + // middle
                word.charAt(word.length-1); // last
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DBL7R/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "random string";

var fml; // first middle last
fml = string[0] + string[Math.floor(string.length / 2)] + string[string.length - 1];
// gives "r g"
```

You might want to add some checks on `string`. If it's an empty string this will fail. It it's shorter than 2 characters you will get duplicates. You could also replace `Math.floor` by `Math.ceil` if you want to round the other way (for strings of even length).